# How to run PHP from Powershell (it works in cmd)

Tags: powershell

PHP is in path, it works in cmd but in Powershell I get cmdlet not recognized.

I also tried

```
& php -v
```

without success

Comment: Try running `get-command php*` and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Invoke-Expression -Command 'cmd.exe /C php -v'
```

Comment: weirdly still doesn't work : 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: If you still have this problem, you can use sysinternals tool procmon (Process Monitor) and watch what happens when you invoke the command and see where it is trying to find the executable.  I've used it to diagnose many problems with apps from desktop to web apps on servers.  Takes a lot of the guesswork out of it, especially something like this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Answer (score 0):

Put the full path to php in the script, or else make sure its folder is in the default paths.